Why does \subitem appear in each index entry for docmfp literate program?
I am working on a Literate Programming project which uses the docmfp package:
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver>
\documentclass[twoside]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{docmfp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[draft=false,
            plainpages=false,
            pdfpagelabels,
            bookmarksnumbered,
            hyperindex=false
           ]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
  \@mparswitchfalse
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{#1}
\pagestyle{headings}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage[columns=1]{idxlayout}
%%% \OnlyDescription
\setcounter{StandardModuleDepth}{1}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{mwe.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%
% \fi
%
% \DoNotIndex{\bullet}
% The first such routine will be appropriately enough, to set up the stock, and perform other
% initializations. \DescribeRoutine{psetupstock}
% \Finale
% \PrintIndex
%
\endinput

but this results in the index entry including odd commands:


you should call makeindex with a suitable style, e.g. makeindex -s gind.ist mwe.

Okay, but I was just using pdflatexmk in TeXshop --- I didn't realize that that default would need to be adjusted.
